# Run MYSQL Query From Submit Button with multiple conditions in php

Tags: php, mysql

my code

```
<form name="rua" method="post">

<input name="Next" type="submit" id="Next" value="Next">                

<?php
if($_REQUEST['Next']=='Next' && (strpos($_POST['ruacombo'], 'Yes') === true && (strpos($drop, 'norm') !== false))) {
{
$sql="UPDATE `RUASEXCELL` SET `$tier_two`=3 WHERE Username = '$username'";
echo $sql;

$final=mysql_query($sql);
if($final)
{
//echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=\">";
}
} 
}

?>
</form>
```

next = submit button

ruacombo = combobox populated by mysql

drop = combobox populated by mysql

i have tried a few variations of this code and cannot seem to get it to work

Thanks

Comment: echo $sql and post the output pls.

Comment: i get a very long error Notice: Undefined variable: drop in file.php on line 165 Warning: strpos() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in file.php on line 165, i know that drop works as i can echo it

Comment: @ids `&& (strpos($_POST['ruacombo'] == 'Yes' && (strpos($drop` causes a problem. I think it should be `&& (strpos($_POST['ruacombo'], 'Yes') === true && (strpos($drop`

Comment: i echoed it above the submit button and it outputs `UPDATE `RUASEXCELL` SET `Immerseus-10-SOO`=3 WHERE Username = 'myusername'`

Comment: I see: You want to use $_POST['drop'] instead of $drop. But please use a more modern API like mysqli or PDO and prepared statements with parameters. Bind those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Fix this from :

```
(strpos($drop, 'norm') !== false)
```

To

```
(strpos($drop, 'norm') != false)
```

`!==` is used to compare if the values are also of the same object type. Which would almost always fail for your case.

Comment: No the use of !== is absolutely correct. Imagine the content of $drop is 'normalize'. The return value of strpos is therefor 0, what evaluates to false. See the warning in the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: drop in file.php on line 165 Warning: strpos() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in file.php on line 165

Comment: I just copy pasted from your code in the question. Did you set the variable $drop before?

Comment: yeah it is set before

Comment: when i do `<?php
if (strpos($drop, 'hc') !== false)
echo 'HEROIC';
else {
echo 'NORMAL';
}

?>` the echo is correct